# A queue of countries

Tags: pattern, geography, flags

This is a **queue of countries**:

> $Ireland, Guinea, Romania, Italy$

**Values:**

> $Ireland = 7$
>   $Guinea = 15$
>   $Romania = 60$
>   $Italy = 87$

[image]

Try to **answer following questions**:

> 1) $Mali$ = ?
>   2) $Iran, rot. 90°$ = ?
>   3) $Bolivia, rot. 90°$ = ?
>   4) $Malta$ = ?
>   5) $Cameroon$ = ?
>   6) $Ukraine, rot. 90°$ = ?
>   7) $Ghana, rot. 90°$ = ?
>   8) $Bulgaria, rot. 90°$ = ?

**Hint 1:**

> Symbols such as stars in flags are unimportant

**Hint 2:**

> Make a queue with the flags of the countries, in the right order.

**Hint 3:**

> Try to create new flags with the queue.

Comment: So it is first color times second color plus third color.

Comment: Yes,  that's true !

Comment: Are there three different shades of red here? And if it matters, in which direction are the rotations?

Comment: No there aren't different shades of red. The rotations can be in both directions, but if you have the right idea you will see it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Making a queue of countries and finding the first appearance of each countries' flag, as well as @Duck's comment, i.e. first number times second number plus third (0 if no third number), I get:

1. $Mali$, Green Yellow Red (Guinea's flag reversed) $9\times 2 + 3 =
       21$

   [image]
2. $Iran, rot. 90°$, Same as Italy, $87$

   [image]
3. $Bolivia, rot. 90°$, Same as Guinea  $15$
4. $Malta$ = White and Red, no third color (Italy's flag) $9\times 6 + 0 = 54$
5. $Cameroon$ = $9\times 4 + 8 = 44$
6. $Ukraine, rot. 90°$ = $7\times 8 = 56$
7. $Ghana, rot. 90°$ = $Guinea$
8. $Bulgaria, rot. 90°$ = $9\times 9 + 4 = 85$